# React Native Navigation - trying to change drawer based on screen

Tags: react-native

I have created a new project with a currently working drawer and hamburger menu, however I am currently trying to change what is displayed in the drawer based on the active page. I can't really share the code easily, due to data... but will share what I can and give an example of whats left. Currently I have:

`app.js` file

```
import Drawer from './routes/homeStack.js';
    export default() => {
       return (
         <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer />
         </NavigationContainer>
       );
    };
```

I have a `home.js` file which is loaded first after the splash screen.

Then, I have two other screens,  `contact.js` and `info.js`.

I have working navigation to the screens mentioned, which will display the appropriate views.

but what I am stuck on is that I am trying to swap out the Drawer contents so that they display different options. So for example the drawers would look like this for each page:

`home.js` drawer:
   
   Contact Us
   
   Information

`contact.js` drawer:
   
   Home
   
   Email Us
   
   Phone Us

`info.js` drawer:
   
   Home
   
   About Us

I am new to React Native, so I am not sure if there is something I need to do in the `app.js` so that it loads the drawer differently based on the current screen dispalyed.

Any additional information anyone can provide is appreciated. I have exhausted other google and stak searches but can't seem to find anything.